# Change date language (months, week days) without changing system locale in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, language, date-format

I have Russian system locale in my Windows 7 (set in CP, Region and Language, Formats, Russian). I'd like to keep it since some Russian programs I need don't work correctly under English locale.

But I don't want to use dates in Russian (январь instead of January, понедельник instead of Monday, etc.).

Any way to achieve it?

Comment: You can create a custom locale that mixes existing ones either as supplemental locale or as a replacement. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317785%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, @Brian. I believe this is the way to go. Will explore it. Please submit it as an answer. It'd be great if you can extend it a little. Maybe by providing direct links to the Locale Builder and a tutorial. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, looks like it doesn't work for Windows 7. Googling...

Comment: The Locale Builder program has problems running in Windows 7, the locales created work fine.

Comment: OK, finally made it work even under Win7. MS made the installation a nightmare, but compatibility mode helps. @Brian, I can accept if you submit it as an answer. Thanks a lot!